# Debug /http-bind/ issue Openfire

Tags: xmpp, openfire

Im using openfire for the xmpp to my website. I have done a server move and relocated the site on the same server as openfire as they were both on different servers before.

Since the move im getting error 500 on the /http-bind/ request on my website.

How can i debug this or what to i need to consider that may be causing the error 500 on /http-bind/

Error log

[warn] proxy: No protocol handler was valid for the URL /http-bind/. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.

Comment: Error log shows [warn] proxy: No protocol handler was valid for the URL /http-bind/. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: You need to load the '[proxy_http](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy_http.html)' module in Apache.

There are some instructions I wrote in the Prosody documentation on [setting up BOSH with Apache](http://prosody.im/doc/setting_up_bosh#proxying_requests), but they should apply equally to any BOSH/XMPP server. In particular I'm not sure whether Openfire is fussy about `/http-bind` vs. `/http-bind/`. Therefore if the below instructions do not work, try adding the `/` to the end of the URL.

**Summary**

Run: `sudo a2enmod rewrite proxy proxy_http`

Add the following lines to your Apache config:

```
<Location /http-bind>
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
</Location>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/http-bind$ http://example.com:5280/http-bind [P,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add that with a properly configured server you can just put this in your .htaccess in the root of your web folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

# Rule1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/chat1/http-bind
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://chatsrv1.joynmenow.com:7070/http-bind/ [P,L]

# Rule 2
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/chat2/http-bind
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://chatsrv2.joynmenow.com:7070/http-bind/ [P,L]

</IfModule>
```

I'm not exactly sure what configs are required to allow this in a .htaccess however my godaddy VPS allowed me to do this in it's default configuration.